# ClassNotFound Exception- SystemPropertiesLoader

Tags: java, spring-mvc, classnotfoundexception

Hi when i tried to run my application am getting this error. any solution??

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mgh.mt.commons.lifecycle.SystemPropertiesLoader
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4709)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1060)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1060)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You will get a better response from asking a clear and concise question.